# Run an arbitrary Azure provider operation

Tags: azure, azure-cli

In the Azure CLI resource manager, we can list providers and their operations.

```
azure provider list 
azure provider operations show Microsoft.Web/sites/*
```

How do we run one of the listed operations. For instance, how would we run this:

```
Operation          :  Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols/web/Read
OperationName      :  Get Web App's source control configuration
ProviderNamespace  :  Microsoft Web Apps                  
ResourceName       :  Web App Source Control                 
Description        :  Get Web App's source control configuration settings.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `azure provider operations show` is to display operations that are supported by the various providers so that you can use them to create custom Role Based Access Control (RBAC) roles. They are not actual commands or endpoints that can be executed.

To create a custom RBAC role, you first create a JSON file describing the role and operations allowed by the role, then pass the file to `azure role create`.

More details here.. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-azure-cli/#create-a-custom-role

Comment: these are also relevant for ARM Template Authoring, as you can leverage any `list*` action to retrieve resource info from various providers to use dynamically in your template. more here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/#_list